# Minecraft Dragon Giltch?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was fighting the ender dragon for the first time and it was definitely there but now it's nowhere to be seen. I went into creative to check it wasn't flying around the island and I went very far but I still couldn't find it. It could be a glitch and it just disappeared but I don't know. If you know what to do them please say.

Comment: Did you killi it?

Answer (score 2):

Since you have creative mode,

To see if the ended dragon is just stalling, try the command while in the end

```
/tp @p @e[type=EnderDragon,c=1]
```

This will teleport you to him, if he is alive. If he is not found, you may just want to create another one yourself. Make sure you are at 0,0 in the end:

```
/summon EnderDragon ~ ~ ~
```